# magento special price product page loads products with wrong dates

Tags: magento, product

I found this tut to create a page with magento products with a special price.
http://workingmagento.blogspot.nl/2011/02/magento-how-to-create-special-price.html

It works fine only with selecting te correct products.

So the script only needs to load products which have a date range where todays date is in. The problem is that it loads product with any date.

Cant find the bug in this script.

Anyone knows the solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
         ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $dateTomorrow), 1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left')
```

make sure these two lines of code is there.
Also check value of $todatDate and $dateTomorrow.

FYI : Code that is on link you stated is not a standard magento code.